# implementing bubble sort program in c

Tags: c

I am just implementing bubble sort in c but i have to be face problem in taking array elements from user its not taking properly, suppose i enter array size 5 after that i am not able to store 5 elements in an array, i wrote this code within main function

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void bubbleSort(int *arr, int size) {
          int temp, i, j;
          for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
                    for(j = 0; j <= size - i -1 ; j++){
                              if(*(arr+j) > *(arr+j+1)) {
                                   temp = *(arr+j);
                                   *(arr+j) = *(arr+j+1);
                                   *(arr+j+1)= temp;
                              }
                    }
          }
}
void display(int *p, int s) {

          for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
                    printf("%d, ", *(p+i));
          }
}

int main() {
         int i, size, arr[size];
         printf("\n Enter Array Size ....");
         scanf("%d", &size);
         printf("\n Enter %d array values...", size);
          for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
          }
          bubbleSort(arr, size);
          display(arr, size);
          return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int size, arr[size]` That won't work because `size` needs to have a value *before* `array` is declared. Declare `array` after the `scanf`. Also, always check the return value of `scanf` to ensure the `size` value is successfully set. It's also a good idea to check that the user doesn't enter invalid values such as negatives and extremely large numbers.

Comment: kaylum is correct. You would need to either allocate the array with a maximal size or allocate it dynamically (`malloc`).

Answer (score 1):

If you run your compiler with warnings turned on (eg in [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) `-Wall` would be an option.) you would see warning similar to the following:

```
Build Status (so.prj - Debug)
 s0_15.c - 1 warning
  25, 27    warning: variable 'size' is uninitialized when used here 
      25, 21    note: initialize the variable 'size' to silence this warning
 Link so.exe
 "c:\Play\so.exe" successfully created.
Build succeeded.
```

A minimal fix to this warning is to simply initialize the variable `size` before using it...

```
int main(void) {
         int i, size;
         printf("\n Enter Array Size ....");
         if(scanf("%d", &size) != 1) {/*handle error and leave*/ }
         if(size <= 0){/*handle error and leave*/ }
         int arr[size];//because this is a VLA, it cannot be 
                       //initialized upon declaration...
         memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);//...so initialize here before using.
         ...
```

( Note that [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are available when using C99, and *optionally* defined in compilers since then.  Read your [compiler documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) to know before attempting this approach. )

Comment: @Imtiyaz - You are welcome.  You can mark one or the other of the answers here as accepted by clicking the hollow check mark.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
int i, size, arr[size];
```

When you declare an array, its size has to be known *at the point of declaration* - it either needs to be a *constant expression* (like `5`), or it needs to be a variable that has been properly initialized or assigned a good value.

At this point, `size` has not been initialized or assigned, and its value is *indeterminate*.  `arr` will be sized to whatever that value is, and if the value is 0 or negative, then the behavior will be undefined.  That size will not change after the declaration, regardless of whatever you store to `size` later on.

So you need to defer the declaration of `arr` until after you've read a value into `size`:

```
int i, size;
printf("\n Enter Array Size ....");
scanf("%d", &size);

int arr[size];
```